# Joint density function | mixed boundries

Tags: probability

I have a $f(x,y) , 0<x<2y<\infty$ joint density function. How are the boundries of $x$ and $y$ decided? $x<2y<+\infty$ or $0<2y<+\infty$ or whatever? I mean, does the relation of x and y matter?

It asks $f(Y|X)$ by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(Y\mid X)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}$$ for $x$ such that $f(x)>0$ and for $0<x<+\infty$
$$f(x)=\int_{Y}f(x,y)dy=\int_{\frac x2}^{+\infty}f(x,y)dy$$ By the way, drawing the domain of $f$ (not $f$ itself) helps always.

Comment: Why the boundy of y is not $0<y<{+\infty}$

Comment: Because $x<2y \iff \frac{x}2<y$.

Comment: So, is boundry of x $0<x<2y$ ?

Comment: No, boundary of $x$ is $0<x<+\infty$.